# Activate move base recovery behaviors

Tags: navigation, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear ROS users, I am writing a nav_core recovery plugin to use with move_base and the trajectory rollout planner. To effectively test my code, I would like to be able to trigger the recovery behavior in someway, or tell the planner to activate a recovery often. In fact, when the robot is stuck, recovery behaviors are not always activated. I tried to lower the value of controller_patience in move base, but it seems that does not work.
Is there a way to tell the planner to activate the recovery behaviors?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/270518/activate-move-base-recovery-behaviors/) by [rastaxe](https://answers.ros.org/users/2870/rastaxe/) on ROS Answers with karma: 620 on 2017-09-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`move_base` will invoke the recovery behaviors on three conditions: An oscillation was discovered, no global plan was received for some amount of time, or the local planner failed to find a valid velocity command for some amount of time. You can try forcing these conditions as test cases?

---

Originally posted by [Sidd](https://answers.ros.org/users/22657/sidd/) with karma: 155 on 2017-09-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rastaxe](https://answers.ros.org/users/2870/rastaxe/) on 2017-09-13**:
Thanks for the answer. In my case, tuning the oscillation_timeout parameter is enough to trigger recovery behaviour. The default value is 0, which means infinite time.

**Comment by [Sidd](https://answers.ros.org/users/22657/sidd/) on 2017-09-22**:
I'm sorry, but I'm confused by your comment. Did you mean that tuning the oscillation parameter fixed your problem?

**Comment by [rastaxe](https://answers.ros.org/users/2870/rastaxe/) on 2017-11-23**:
yes, putting a small value (not zero) on the oscillation_timeout triggers the recovery behaviour very often, which was what I was looking for (only for testing my plugin).